# Validate FK relationship through constraints, trigger, or design

Tags: sql-server, database-design, constraints, database-trigger

I'm attempting to model a few relationships and I have repeatedly run into the same problem across a few.

What I am attempting to do, either through the use of check constraints, triggers, or redesigning tables is to ensure "correct" FK references.

Consider the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
    [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location]
    [LocationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Location] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location] ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Location_CustomerID_Customer] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerID])

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerDivision]
    [CustomerDivisionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomerDivision] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerDivision] ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CustomerDivision_CustomerID_Customer] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerID])

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LocationDivision]
    [LocationDivisionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LocationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerDivisionID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LocationDivision_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LocationDivision] ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LocationDivision_LocationID_Location] FOREIGN KEY([LocationID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([LocationID])
```

`Divisions` and `Locations` are both owned by `Customers`, but only select `Divisions` apply to a particular `Location`.

I am struggling to come up with a simple way to ensure that only `LocationDivisons` receive a "valid" `CustomerDivisionID` foreign key reference if `CustomerDivision.CustomerID = Location.CustomerID`

**Adding additional explanation**

```
dbo.Customer(CustomerID,Name)
VALUES (1,Customer 1),
       (2,Customer 2)

dbo.Location(LocationID, CustomerID, Name)
VALUES (1,1,Location 1),
       (2,2,Location 2)

dbo.CustomerDivision(CustomerDivisionID, CustomerID, Name)
VALUES (1,1,Customer 1 Division 1),
       (2,1,Customer 1 Division 2)

dbo.LocationDivisionID(LocationDivisionID, LocationID, CustomerDivisionID)
VALUES (1,1,1),
       (2,2,1)   <---- This should fail as the this CustomerDivision.CustomerID <> Location.CustomerID
```

Comment: If a Customer "owns" a Location, and Division only applies to a specific Location, then it looks like you have your foreign key in Division pointing to the wrong place. It should be pointing to Location, not Customer. you can infer the customer because of whom the location is related to.

Comment: The Division applies to the customer and location. The CustomerDivisions table is meant to model all possible Divisions that could apply for that particular Customers Locations.

Comment: So a Location *actually* belongs to a Division and Customer?

Comment: I modified the question to be a bit more clear with an example.